# OPC UA asyncua python: new folder created but server never returns the methods

Tags: python, opc

I need to create a folder on an OPC UA-Server. I use the python asyncua lib. I receive the the NodeId of new folder which is stored in new_folder_id. In the next step I need to create a file. Therefore I need to use the CreateFile method. In the while loop I ask periodically (every 3 seconds) the server if the methods like CreateFile are created for the new folder. By purpose I programmed and endless loop to see if receive a positive response. The problem is that even after a couple of minutes the loop does not terminate. Any ideas why?

```
from asyncua import Client
import asyncio 
 async with Client(url=self._endpoint) as client:
     # Create the directory on the OPC server 
     folder_node = client.get_node(node_id) 
     new_folder_id = await folder_node.call_method("32:CreateDirectory", new_folder_name) 
     
     while True: 
        new_folder = client.get_node(new_folder_id)
        methods = await new_folder.get_methods() 
        if len(methods): 
           break
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

I expect that the server returns the created methods for the new folder