# OPC UA asyncua python: new file directory created but it lacks the CreateFile method among its children

Tags: python, file-transfer, opc-ua

My problem appears to be very similar to this unanswered question: [OPC UA asyncua python: new folder created but server never returns the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117089/opc-ua-asyncua-python-new-folder-created-but-server-never-returns-the-methods) but I have tried something slightly different.
I initially tried to create a folder by calling the existing create_folder method, but that folder just appeared to be one I could place other nodes (or folders) inside rather than actual files, and I was trying to add support for transferring a file to the OPC-UA server. Instead the type that seemed to fit what I wanted was FileDirectory, which I could see in standard_address_space_services should have CreateFile as a child (precisely what is searched for in the create_file method of UaDirectory). To that end I created this method, largely copied from the create_folder method:

```
    async def add_directory(self, nodeid, bname):
        # This section was mostly copied from manage_nodes.create_folder
        nodeid, qname = _parse_nodeid_qname(nodeid, bname)
        parent = self.server.nodes.objects
        directory_node = make_node(
            self.server,
            await _create_object(parent.server, parent.nodeid,
                                 nodeid, qname, ua.ObjectIds.FileDirectoryType)
        )
        # This was mostly copied from standard_address_space_services
        # It doesn't currently work because self.server doesn't have an add_nodes method
        # standard_address_space_services.create_standard_address_space_Services gets called
        # when the internal server is initialized
        # But this doesn't result in any instance of the FileDirectoryType I create
        # having CreateFile as a child node
        # CreateFile is created as a child of node id 13354, "<FileDirectoryName>"
        # Which in turn is a child of 13353, FileDirectoryType, which I use above
        # attrs = ua.MethodAttributes(
        #     DisplayName=LocalizedText("CreateFile"),
        # )
        # node = ua.AddNodesItem(
        #     BrowseName=QualifiedName("CreateFile", 0),
        #     NodeClass_=NodeClass.Method,
        #     ParentNodeId=NumericNodeId(directory_node.nodeid.Identifier, 0),
        #     ReferenceTypeId=NumericNodeId(47, 0),
        #     NodeAttributes=attrs,
        # )
        # self.server.add_nodes([node])
        return directory_node
```

Unfortunately, as indicated by those comments, merely creating an object with the FileDirectory type doesn't give it the methods specified in the standard services and hence it will still fail if I call create_file on it. The FileDirectory type must have been added for a reason, but I can't see how to create a working instance of one.
These are the lines I use attempting to create a file with a node created by the method above:

```
ua_directory = UaDirectory(transfer_folder_node)
transfer_file = await ua_directory.create_file("test_file.txt", True)
```